# Does $f'(x) = f(\ln(x))$ have an easily expressed solution?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

This is motivated by [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/93729/how-many-fours-are-needed-to-represent-numbers-up-to-n), where we can consider a bound of the form $f((n+1)!) - f(n!) \le 2f(n)$. To find a function with a similar growth rate, I wondered if there's a technique for solving differential equations of the form
$$f'(x) = f(\ln(x))$$ or equivalently $$f'(e^y) = f(y).$$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm working over the reals.  I think your function would be very complicated if it exists.  It certainly wouldn't be smooth.  To see that, consider the second derivative of $f$, for example.
$$
f^{\prime\prime}(x) = f^\prime(\ln x)/x = f(\ln\ln x)/x\,.
$$
Further differentiation will produce a term in the expression for $f^{(n)}(x)$ which involve $n$ iterated logarithms of $x$.  For any arbitrary $x$, some number of logarithms will be "too many" and result in taking the logarithm of a negative number.  So, for any $x$, we can find $n$ such that the $n$th derivative of $f$ does not exist, and hence $f$ couldn't be smooth, or even $C^n$.

Comment: Indeed, I think that will likely rule out what I was thinking of as "easily expressed." Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

So, wouldn't the usual thing be like this...
Define $f$ arbitrarily in $[1,e]$, then for $x>e$ define
$$
f(x) = f(e) + \int_e^x f'(t)\,dt = f(e)+\int_e^x f(\log t)\,dt ,
$$
and for $y<1$ define $f(y) = f'(e^y)$.  The problem then is to make it match at the endpoints.