# Can we make any positive integer from one $4$ and a finite number of $\lfloor x\rfloor$, $\Gamma$ and $\sqrt{}$?

Tags: radicals, puzzle, gamma-function, ceiling-and-floor-functions

For those who aren't aware, [Four Fours](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Four_fours) is a puzzle where the objective is to express as many consecutive integers as possible, starting from 1, using a finite number of allowed operations and (as the name suggests) four 4s.

Now, a Discord server I am in is doing this puzzle collectively. To make things easier we have tried to devise a list of possible numbers that can be created from a single $4$ and a series of permitted operations applied to it, so that the problem then becomes "create [insert number] by adding, multiplying, subtracting and dividing these numbers".

During the process of this, one person created a conjecture: perhaps it is possible to create *all* positive using a single $4$ with a finite number of floor, gamma and square root function applied to it. For example, one could write

$$\left\lfloor\sqrt{\sqrt{\Gamma\left(\sqrt{\Gamma(\Gamma(4))}\right)}}\right\rfloor=42$$

And thus you can use a combination floor, gamma and square root functions applied to a $4$ to get $42$.

It may be worth mentioning that somebody managed to check that it is indeed possible to get all numbers between $1$ and $142$ through this method, but couldn't check any further due to overflow issues.

(Note: similar to [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/93729/how-many-fours-are-needed-to-represent-numbers-up-to-n), but we allow the floor function here)

Comment: This is equivalent to Knuth's Conjecture and is an open problem. See [A139004](https://oeis.org/A139004) where they [represent all numbers up to $1000$](https://oeis.org/A139004/a139004.txt), and *"D. E. Knuth, Representing numbers using only one 4, Mathematics Magazine, Vol. 37, No. 5 (Nov. 1964), pp. 308-310."*